# Show only data in array in var_dump

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to show only 1 data in array.

My code right now:

```
var_dump($ranked);
```

In others cases, I have used `echo $ranked->tier` but in array this won't work.

Comment: var_dump($ranked["tier"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
echo $ranked['tier'];
```

Comment: i try this before 

Undefined index: tier

Comment: then `tier` does not exist. can you do `print_r($ranked);` and tell me if you see `tier` anywhere?

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [tier] => DIAMOND [queueType] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5 [rank] => IV [playerOrTeamId] => 422074 [playerOrTeamName] => Maziiinho [leaguePoints] => 50 [wins] => 112 [losses] => 108 [veteran] => 1 [inactive] => [freshBlood] => [hotStreak] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [tier] => PLATINUM [queueType] => RANKED_FLEX_SR [rank] => II [playerOrTeamId] => 422074 [playerOrTeamName] => Maziiinho [leaguePoints] => 9 [wins] => 21 [losses] => 16 [veteran] => [inactive] => [freshBlood] => [hotStreak] => ) )

Comment: Then to get tier you have to do `echo $ranked[0]->tier;` or `echo $ranked[1]->tier;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($ranked['tier']);
```

or:

```
echo $ranked['tier'];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.